# How to use parcable while using Json?

Tags: android

I have this json code that get `id` and `name` from server but I cant    startActivity(intent);in the json. actually can I just insert the data in parcable class without starting intent ?

```
try {

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
            peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");
            System.out.println(peoples.length());

            Listitem = new ArrayList<Listitem>();
            for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
                JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
              //  String id ="2";
                String id=  c.getString("ID");
                String url = c.getString("URL");
                Log.d("Id: ", id);
                int intid = 0;
                Student student = new Student(c.getString("ID"),
                        "hhe",
                        c.getString("URL")
                        );
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,);

                // Passing data as a parecelable object to StudentViewActivity
                intent.putExtra("student",student);

                // Opening the activity
                startActivity(intent);
                try {
                    intid = Integer.parseInt(id.toString());
                } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
                }
```

this is parcable class

```
public class Student implements Parcelable{
    String mSid;
    String mSName;
    String mSUrl;


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * Storing the Student data to Parcel object
     **/
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(mSid);
        dest.writeString(mSName);
        dest.writeString(mSUrl);
    }

    /**
     * A constructor that initializes the Student object
     **/
    public Student(String mSid,String sName, String mSUrl ){
        this.mSid = mSid;
        this.mSName = sName;
        this.mSUrl = mSUrl;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieving Student data from Parcel object
     * This constructor is invoked by the method createFromParcel(Parcel source) of
     * the object CREATOR
     **/
    private Student(Parcel in){
        this.mSid = in.readString();
        this.mSName = in.readString();
        this.mSUrl = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Student> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Student>() {

        @Override
        public Student createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Student(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Student[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Student[size];
        }
    };
}
```

I am having error on `startactivity`

[image]

edit

This in main activity i am receiving the arraylist `result`... And I am passing to Gridview Adapter

```
    public void downloadImage() {
       // OkHttpHandler handler = new OkHttpHandler();

        OkHttpHandler handler = new OkHttpHandler(MainActivity.this,new OkHttpHandler.MyInterface() {
            @Override
            public void myMethod(ArrayList result) {
                                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connection Succesful",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  GridViewAdapter adapter = new GridViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.grid_item_layout, result);

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        });

        handler.execute();
        String image = null;

        try {

            image = handler.execute().get();
            Log.d("e", "hhhh handler");
System.out.print(image);
            //if (image != null && image.length > 0){
              //  Log.isLoggable("e",image.length);
                //Log.d("e", "ddddddd entered the try");
          //      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
            //    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
  //              txtBytes.setText("Total bytes downloaded: " + image.length);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("e", "rrrrrr error");

            e.printStackTrace();
//            txtBytes.setText("Hmm sorry, something went wrong!");
        }

    }
```

this is gridview adapter , how to pass the arraylist data to next sibleviewactivity to post the name and id ?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    System.out.println("entering adapter1");

    View row = convertView;
  final  ViewHolder holder;


    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext);
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    final Listitem item = getItem(position);
    System.out.println("item.getUrl() ");
    System.out.println(item.getUrl());
    Picasso.with(mcontext).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
    holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getId());
    Picasso.
            with(mcontext).
            load(item.getUrl())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
            .fit()
            .noFade()
            .into(holder.imageView);

    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.d("OnImageButton", "Clicked");


            Intent intnt  =new Intent(mcontext, SingleViewActivity.class);
         //   intnt.putExtra("Contact_list", item);
            intnt.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


            mcontext.startActivity(intnt)  ; //This line raises error


            Toast.makeText(mcontext, "intent",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


    return row;
}
```

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: ` can I just insert the data in parcable class without starting intent ?` what does that mean? and use Log instead of System.out.println().

Comment: @JDev check my edit .. I added a screenshot

Comment: @k0sh check my edit please

Comment: Try `mContext.startActivity(intent)`

Comment: @Sourabh it worked but can I add the json into the intent without going to another activity ?

Comment: You can do it .just not statActivity.

Comment: JSON or JSONObject? JSON is just a string and yes you can add it. JSONObject is neither Serializable not Parcelable so no you can't put them in intent. You can extend JSONObject to make it Serializable but I don't know if it'll work so you are better off with using a parcelable POJO

Comment: @Sourabh I have Jsonobject (I am getting id and name from server), I want to send them to a gridview, then in the gridview if I click on an image I want to get this name and id. they suggest to use parcable I didnt know how to do that ?

Comment: @Sourabh In my code now I am sending jsobject to another activity throught arraylist , but I didnt know how to send this arraylist to another activity... did understand what I am doing ? can you help me?

Comment: @tinysunlight is it a good practice to do that ? check my above comment what I am trying to do

Comment: When you Student student = new Student(c.getString("ID"),
                        "hhe",
                        c.getString("URL")
                        ); you have get the parcable. just add them in a arraylist . And set the arraylist as data of a adapter

Comment: startActivity should be add when you click gridview item.

Comment: @tinysunlight check my edit now please , I hope you can help me. if you have anyquestion feel free to ask

Comment: final Listitem item = getItem(position); What't you code in getItem? this listitem is a Student. just putExtra("student",student) in your OnClickListener.

Comment: @tinysunlight  am having error in putextra .. I add it like this in onclicklistner     Intent intnt  =new Intent(mcontext, SingleViewActivity.class);
               intnt.putExtra("Contact_list", item);
                intnt.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                mcontext.startActivity(intnt)  ; //This line raises error

Comment: Plz show the error screenshot. try remove intnt.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: @tinysunlight check my edit plz

Comment: final Listitem item = getItem(position);  Did you change this line ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95849/discussion-between-tiny-sunlight-and-moudiz).

Comment: @tinysunlight you still there can you sill help me ? and no i didnt changed the line

Comment: You should change. 
final Student item = (Student)getItem(position).And where were the Listitem come from？I'm at work, and I will contact you at night.

Comment: @tinysunlight okay I am waiting for you man, when you arrive ill postthe listem

Comment: you use arraylist of Student as data of adapter . So you should return Student in getItem().